# Cannot edit order if payment method is cash on delivery in prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have been searching for an answer to this question for a few hours now, but I can't find anything relevant.

The problem is the following: If i make an order and I choose to pay with bankwire or check, then I can edit, delete and add products to that specific order. If I use cash on delivery or another module that does the same thing then the buttons for edit, delete and add are not there.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Or at least point me in the right direction? I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the payment method is cash on delivery it creates the order with a different order state (preparation in progress) than with bank wire (awaiting confirmation). The order state "preparation in progress", by default, sets the order as paid and/or as validated. When paid, it doesn't allow the order to be altered.

You have 2 solutions, either change the order state "preparation in progress" in backoffice to not set the order paid and not validated, or override the module cash on delivery to use a different order state when creating the order.

Comment: I tried changing the order state to all the other orders, but i still cannot edit the product list. I also modified the "preparation in progress" state so it won't set the order as "paid". Any other ideeas?

Comment: It wont work for the existing orders, only for new ones. and you need to edit the options of the Preparation in progress located in Orders->Statuses

Comment: I changed the options for Preparation in progress in Orders->Statuses. The only options checked are "Allow a customer to download and view PDF versions of his/her invoices." and "Send email when order status is changed", everything else is unchecked. I added a new order and nothing happens. I tried to change the status of the new order but again ... no change :(

Comment: try removing the allow view of pdf. maybe  to have the pdf, the order is considered valid. leave only the send an emal option.

Comment: Nvm, it was my bad, I was editing the wrong Status. After editing the "Processing in progress" status and leaving only the send an email option, it worked like a charm. Thank so much for the help!